# "Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements"

Tags: mysql

I get this error after trying to open MySQL from the terminal:

> ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Comment: A quick google search resulted in https://ostechnix.com/fix-mysql-error-1819-hy000-your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements/

Comment: `Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements` - make the password stronger

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty self-explanatory: you have to choose a stronger password (or set a less strict policy).

The Validate Password component in MySQL evaluates a password strength. To see current settings, type this command at the MySQL prompt:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

The policy is set in the variable `validate_password.policy` which can take one of these values:

- LOW: Password must be composed of a number of chars at least equal to the value defined in the variable `validate_password.length`, or more
- MEDIUM: As above, plus password must contain numeric, mixed case, and special characters; how many, it depends on the value of other `validate_password%` variables
- STRONG: As all above, plus password is cross-checked against a dictionary defined in the variable `validate_password.dictionary_file`